# jquery ui popup box draggable is buggy

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

I am working with Jquery UI and their popup display box.  The box is draggable, and i like that.  It works perfectly in Chrome, however when in IE or Firefox it doesn't work like it should.  (Yes both are up to date)

If I try to drag the box, the box disappears, and i have to scroll half way down the page to find it.

Why does this happen?  How do I fix it?  And if i can't fix it, How do I turn of Draggable?

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            heightStyle: "content"
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        $( "#ticket_view" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "drop",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "scale",
                duration: 1000
            }
        });

        $( ".ticket_viewer" ).click(function() {
            var ticket_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#ticket_view').load('ticketPopup/'+ticket_id);
            $( "#ticket_view" ).dialog( "open" );
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Might be a CSS issue. Are you serving the same styles to Chrome and the other browsers?

Comment: I have not touched jquery-ui's css at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And if i can't fix it, How do I turn of Draggable?

To deactivate draggability, add this to your "draggable" code:

```
draggable: false
```

API docs here: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-draggable

Can you provide a link to the page that it is happening on? Ane what version of jQuery?

Comment: Thank you for the draggabl: flase.  That does stop it from being moved.  Currently it is on my local machine and the site will not go live for another month.  The version is jquery-ui - v1.10.4

Comment: Ah I see. Well my answer will solve somewhat until resolved I suppose. You may try updating UI, v1.11.1 is current stable. What do you see in the inspector tool when dragging the dialog around? How does it differ in FF and IE than Chrome? Furthermore, if you go to http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ in FF or IE, do you notice it jumps around like your localhost?